# Slide out div on form submit element

Tags: jquery, html, css

New to writing jQuery and could use some help.

I have a hidden div that I want to slide out when a form element is clicked. However when I use the `.click()` function the data doesn't get submitted and when I use the `.submit()` function the div doesn't slide out.

I would also like it to know if the div is out already and then not animate.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Here is code. http://jsfiddle.net/gZWby/23/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.purchase_button').submit(function () {
        if ($("#top_margin").css("top") == "-135px") {
            $("#top_margin").animate({
                top: "0px"
            }, 500);
            $("#total_wrap").animate({
                top: "0px"
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $("#top_margin").animate({
                top: "-135px"
            }, 500);
            $("#total_wrap").animate({
                top: "-135px"
            }, 500);
        }
        return false;

    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="top_margin"></div>
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="smokehouse_1_ATC" class="purchase_button">
</form>
```

CSS:

```css
#top_margin {
    width:100%;
    height: 140px;
    background-color:orange;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    /*I would like this div to always be fixed to the top of the browser window*/
    top: -135px;
    left: 0;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-top:5px;
}

input.shop_button, input.purchase_button {
    width:143px;
    background-color:black;
    border:none;
    color:#74cccc;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

input.shop_button:hover, input.purchase_button:hover {
    color:#ff3636;
}
```

Comment: basically you need to put hidden inputs on the form and when they fill out the pull out inputs you need to copy them to the hidden inputs. then you will get your data submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following answer should solve both your problems.**

You're targeting the wrong element for submit.  You need to change your `$('.purchase_button').submit(fn(){...})` to this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){ 
 //YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

The reason is that the button itself does not have a "submit" event.  Only the form does.  Therefore, we need to listen for "submit" on the form itself instead of the button.

Also, if you want to leave it out after the submit, then you need to trim the `else` block from your `if` statement.  That's only there to slide it back up. Check the fiddle for the correct code.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gZWby/27/)

**UPDATE**

A comment on this answer points to what's stopping your submit from being executed. You have a `return false` within your Javascript, which prevents the submit from firing as the event listener is fired before the submit actually occurs. The `return false` is a common method for prevention of form submits in the case of failed validation.

**UPDATE 2**

If you'd like to stay on the page, and therefore keep the slider out, you'll have to do something other than a traditional form submit.  Traditional submits will rely on an `action` method to post to another page, or lacking a defined action method, will post back to the same page.  Either way, you're bound for a refresh.  In order to do a form submit without that happening, might I suggest the [jQuery Forms Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)?

Using that plugin, your jQuery would look like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('form').ajaxForm(function() { 
     $("#top_margin").animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, 500);
        $("#total_wrap").animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, 500); 
   });
});
```

And you could cut the rest of it out completely.

Comment: Thank you so much it now slides but the data isn't submitting. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Change the script to return true. Returning false means the submission process is canceled. This is used to validate the form.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is now submitting but the slide isn't working now. http://jsfiddle.net/gZWby/28/

Comment: It sounds like what you want, then, is an ajax submit.  I'll update the fiddle.  Otherwise, on your form submit you'll be pushing the user to the `action` property of your form tag.  No action property, and the page will refresh.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont see any difference in the fiddle.? Still not working.

Comment: You're right.  I never updated the fiddle.  But the code in the update is what you want.  It's hard to demonstrate a `POST` when there's nothing reasonable to post to.

Comment: That jquery plugin is brilliant Josh! Thanks so much! Cheers.

Comment: Glad to hear you're liking it.  If this post was sufficient to solve your problem, please don't forget to mark it as your answer.  Thanks!